# Computation of $\int_a^b x f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$, where $f$ is the log-normal density function

Tags: integration, statistics, density-function

I'm trying to evaluate the following integral:
$$
\int\limits_a^b x f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
where $f$ is the probability density function of the log-normal distribution.

If $a=0$ and $b=\infty$, the result is (I think) the mean, $\exp({\mu +\sigma ^{2}/2})$. Looking at the PDF, the result should be some simple function involving $\Phi$ or $\phi$, the CDF or PDF of the normal distribution; but I can't get it to work. I'm sure this is a standard result, but ... can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Ok, further searching pointed me to the answer embedded in this similar question here... [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9501/is-it-possible-to-analytically-integrate-x-multiplied-by-the-lognormal-probabi)

Comment: You can find a cute trick to get the expected value here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065914/expected-value-of-lognormal-distribution